# Validate Selectize.js fields with Bootstrap 3 Validator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, selectize.js, bootstrapvalidator

I'm currently working on a form where i've implemented the [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) and [Bootstrap 3 Validator plugin](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/). Now I've a problem with the validation of the selectize input fields on submitting the form.

When I submit the form without selecting any option for the required fields, the validation will work and says that the field must be filled. But when I select a option for all the required fields after the validation and submit the form again, it will always say that the selectize fields are not validated/empty.

```
// a required selectize field    
<div class="form-group has-error has-danger" data-field-id="42">

    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="field-42-selectized">
        Some field * </label>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="field-input selectize selectized" data-field="42" name="field[42]" id="field-42" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        </select>
        <div class="selectize-control field-input selectize single plugin-remove_button">
            <div class="selectize-input items required invalid not-full has-options">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="field-42-selectized" placeholder="-" required="" style="width: 8.51563px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;">
            </div>
            <div class="selectize-dropdown single field-input selectize plugin-remove_button" style="display: none; width: 726.656px; top: 38px; left: 0px; visibility: visible;">
                <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
                    <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="1">
                        data1
                    </div>
                    <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="2">
                        dat2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've done some debugging and found the place where it goes wrong namely here:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="field-42-selectized" placeholder="-" required="" style="width: 8.51563px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;">
```